# How can you calculate how long life will last with a regular run in terms of special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, time-dilation

Imagine, John run everyday 10 km with speed 12 km/h towards the east along the equator. If he had not run, he would have died at 70 from the point of view of a motionless observer. How long will John live from the point of view of a stationary observer with a regular run? Is there a formula for solving such problems?

Let's neglect the improvement of various biological processes in the body with regular running and another kinds of sports. Let's also neglect John's movements, with the exception of such a run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you describes has thousands of potential variables that might play a role in the outcome, such as the weather each day, the clothes John wears each day, the route he follows on each run. However, if you ignore those, and you assume that John does exactly the same run every day, going 5km directly to the East then returning, while the stationary observer never moves, then you have a low-speed instance of the 'twin paradox', and you can indeed calculate the reduction in John's ageing that arises from the consequence of his motion. You can find the relevant formula by googling the 'twin paradox' (I am too tired to type it). My guess is that the effect of the movement you describe will be less than a trillionth of a second.

Comment: The back of my envelope says about 14 billionths of a second (American billionths, not British) but there's probably a 50% chance I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @WillO Ha! I woke in the night and found myself trying to sanity check my guess through some pretty suspect mental arithmetic. I need to get a life!

Comment: John goes 10 km east each day, he doesn't return. Presumably, we're ignoring the fact that you can't run on water at 12 km/h. ;)